# Apache Spark java heap space error during matrix multiplication

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 2.0.1 with two workers (one executor each) with 20Gb each. And run following code:

```
JavaRDD<MatrixEntry> entries = ...; // filing the data
CoordinateMatrix cmatrix = new CoordinateMatrix(entries.rdd());
BlockMatrix matrix = cmatrix.toBlockMatrix(100, 1000);
BlockMatrix cooc = matrix.transpose().multiply(matrix);
```

My matrix contains 10 000 000 non-empty cells (each equals to 1.0) and has approx. 3000 columns. Not so big data. But during multiplications I always get:

```
17/01/24 08:03:10 WARN TaskMemoryManager: leak 1322.6 MB memory from org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap@649e7019
17/01/24 08:03:10 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 57.0 (TID 83664)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseMatrix$.zeros(Matrices.scala:453)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix$class.multiply(Matrices.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseMatrix.multiply(Matrices.scala:565)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(BlockMatrix.scala:483)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$9$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(BlockMatrix.scala:480)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(BlockMatrix.scala:480)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(BlockMatrix.scala:479)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer$$anon$1.foreach(CompactBuffer.scala:115)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer.foreach(CompactBuffer.scala:30)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer.flatMap(CompactBuffer.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix$$anonfun$23.apply(BlockMatrix.scala:479)
        at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix$$anonfun$23.apply(BlockMatrix.scala:478)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

Now I'm even trying to use only one core per executor.
What can be the problem? And how can I debug it and find root cause? Thanks.

Upd.: Details of failed stage:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.flatMap(RDD.scala:374)
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix.multiply(BlockMatrix.scala:478)
MyClass.generate(SimilarityGenerator.java:57)
MyClass.main(GenerateSimilarity.java:54)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: That's 30 billion doubles, or ~240 GB of RAM just for the matrix.  Then there's memory required for the vector and the result.  OOME seems quite clear.  How much physical memory do you have?  How much is allocated to the JVM?  The best way to figure it out is to use a profiler like VisualVM to see what the generations are doing.  Are you using JDK 8?  It doesn't have perm gen anymore.

Comment: Each worker has 2Tb hard drive mounted, executor-memory is 20Gb. Yes, I'm using JDK 8. Can I use VisualVM if spark is running on console-only cluster? Also, should Spark swap some partitions to HDD and use RAM only for small number of them?

Comment: 20Gb out of 32Gb available, but rest is supposed to be used by Cassandra.

Comment: Hard drive is irrelevant to JVM.  Let's do the math again: 30 billion double values, 8 bytes per double, means ~240 GB just to hold your matrix.  If that math is correct, 240 > 20.  Hence OOME.  What did I miss?

Comment: That I'm using Apache Spark and hope it is smart enough to not hold everything in memory. Matrix should be divided into blocks (default is 1024x1024) and only some of them should be in memory at any given moment of time.

Comment: Sounds like the JVM is telling you that your hopes have been dashed.

Comment: Try to reduce block size. Let's say `cmatrix.toBlockMatrix(50, 50)`.

Comment: Have you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Yes, my colleague found a problem, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared that sparse matrix multiplication is not implemented in a way I thought about it. Spark naturally multiplies block matrices even with zeros in almost all cells. We implemented our own multiplication. Here is Scala code (so also copied from some place):

```
def multiply(left: CoordinateMatrix, right: CoordinateMatrix): CoordinateMatrix = {
  val leftEntries = left.entries.map({ case MatrixEntry(i, j, v) => (j, (i, v)) })
  val rightEntries = right.entries.map({ case MatrixEntry(j, k, w) => (j, (k, w)) })

  val productEntries = leftEntries
    .join(rightEntries)
    .map({ case (_, ((i, v), (k, w))) => ((i, k), (v * w)) })
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .map({ case ((i, k), sum) => MatrixEntry(i, k, sum) })

  new CoordinateMatrix(productEntries)
}
```